# Phonegap (NOT Cordova) 3.5 sample app not firing deviceready

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I noticed today that: sudo npm update -g phonegap showed that v3.5 was available. After doing this update, phonegap -v returns: 3.5.0-0.20.4

I then proceeded to create a sample app using the Phonegap CLI:

- cd myProjectFolder
- phonegap create HelloPhoneGap350
- cd HelloPhoneGap350
- phonegap local build ios (to add the ios platform)
- phonegap run ios --emulator

At this point, the sample app launches. However, deviceready event never gets called. (I added some alert code and can see that the app.initialize() and app.bindEvents() get called. But onDeviceReady never gets called. I was also able to reproduce this with an Android build.

A few weeks ago, I went through exactly the same process with the previous version of Phonegap (v3.4.0-0.20.0) to create a HelloWorld340 which works fine and does call the onDeviceReady function.

I realize that the Phonegap 3.5.0 packaging of cordova 3.5.0 has only been out a few days. Perhaps it's a bug in the packaging? Anyone have any ideas or solutions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More interesting observations over the past few days. I went through the process to create a few more projects. (I'm migrating a bunch of old PhoneGap apps to the new PhoneGap 3.5 and it's easier to create new, sample projects and just move the existing HTML/JS/CSS code over...)

During this work, I noticed that - with a few specific steps - the generated project can fire "deviceready" out of the box. Here are the details:

- I noticed that the phonegap.js file does seem to get put in the right place (yourProjectName/platforms/ios/www/phonegap.js) when the application is created from the command line.

However, upon first launch of the project with Xcode, it doesn't seem to be noticed even though it's in the "Staging/www" view within Xcode. However, if you following procedure, the rebuild in Xcode seems to notice that it's there and package up the right bits to push to the device/emulator.

- CLI: phonegap local build ios
- Xcode: Product - Clean <-- this seem to be the important step.
- Xcode: Product - Build/Run

(Note, however, that the cordova.js file that appears in the initial creation of platforms/ios/www doesn't get removed. So, you end up with 2 copies of the same file with different names: cordova.js and phonegap.js)

With this approach, you don't have to edit the generated index.html solution (mentioned as another solution/workaround in this thread).

Answer (score 1):

well, im using 3.5.0-0.2.4 and it works like a charm.
perhaps you forget to inherit the cordova.js-file?

Comment: Hmmm... This was at least a poke in the right direction... Upon further review, the right cordova.js file was placed in platforms/ios/www BUT note that the file there is cordova.js. However, the index.html refers to loading phonegap.js. So, changing the reference in index.html solved the problem. Seems like a bug in the PhoneGap project generation process.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the suggestion by brauchle_andi above, I dug deeper and found the problem and just reproduced it in a 'clean' generated project.

I am using PhoneGap 3.5.0-0.20.4

I generated a new project (details) below and the file **cordova.js** is placed in the proper platforms/ios/www folder

However, the generated **index.html** has a reference to loading the script file, **phonegap.js**. Editing the index.html to load **cordova.js** fixes this problem.

Seems like a bug in the PhoneGap packaging process.

Here are the steps taken to reproduce this problem:

- Use npm to install (though I may have done an update, don't recall) PhoneGap 3.5.0-0.20.4
- cd Documents/PhoneGapProjects (the folder where I put my Hello World programs)
- phonegap create /Users/John_Arnold/Documents/PhoneGapProjects/HelloPhoneGap350A -i "com.phonegap.HelloPhoneGap350A" -n "HelloPhoneGap350A"
- phonegap run ios --emulator

This creates the project with the problem described above. Editing index.html and re-running the project fixes it.