# Ionic app runs in browser, but fails on Android: [ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

[My App](https://github.com/moroshko/ionic-firebase) is based on the [Ionic sidemenu starter project](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/).
It works fine in a browser, but trying to run it on my Android device results in an [alert](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1893981/Screenshots/la13.png) with the following message:

> [ERROR] Error initializing Cordova: Class not found

I tried the suggested solutions in [this post](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/erroe-error-initializing-cordova-class-not-found-only-on-android/3555), but none of them solved the issue.

To reproduce the issue, please follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/moroshko/ionic-firebase).

Any ideas what's going on?

---

Some info:

```
$ cordova --version
3.5.0-0.2.6

$ ionic --version
Installed Ionic CLI version: 1.1.1-beta3

# In browser's console
> ionic.version === "1.0.0-beta.9"
```

---

Related question: [ui-router resolve behaves strangely in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24945731/247243)

Comment: Stupid question, but do you have the cordova.js script tag in your head tag? (<script src="cordova.js"></script>)

Comment: Same as Andrew, although it will be 404 in development you will need it for testing on devices.

Comment: @AndrewMcGivery @ceyquem Yes, `cordova.js` is there: https://github.com/moroshko/ionic-firebase/blob/master/www/index.html#L17

Comment: Perhaps check if this is your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24185835/1521230 Apparently, 3.5 has some bugs.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem. From my investigation it seems that the problem relates to [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945731/ui-router-resolve-behaves-strangely-in-ionic).

Comment: Put scripts at the bottom of your page, just inside the body tag

Answer (score 7):

I've had this error before.  It can be tricky since it is super generic. I'm not sure if this is related, but after much trouble I was able to resolve my problem using these steps:

1. Make a backup of the .json files inside of your /plugins directory.
2. Remove the .json files in your /plugins directory.
3. Empty your platform directories.
4. Re-add the platforms you want.
5. Build your app again.

Also, I have my cordova.js at the very bottom of my body tag, not in the head as I've seen suggested elsewhere. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: You can also use the commands `cordova platform remove` and `cordova platform add`

Comment: Just a sidenote all cordova commands are proxied through ionic, so you can do ionic platform remove and all the other cordova commands.

Comment: @JimTheDev: Thank god for your reply :-)!