# ui-router resolve behaves strangely in Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I started from a demo Ionic app (`ionic start myApp sidemenu`), [and added a `resolve` to one of the views](https://github.com/moroshko/ResolveIssue/commit/99978540f106cd640a467e080288476d0a105fe5):

```
resolve: {
  issue: function($q, $timeout) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    //defer.reject();       // Doesn't work browser or device
    $timeout(defer.reject); // Works in browser, but not device
    return defer.promise;
  }
}
```

I monitor rejected `resolve`s here:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $ionicLoading) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // regular stuff here

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function() {
      $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'All good!'
      });
    });
  });
});
```

For some reason, if `resolve` rejects immediately (see `defer.reject()` above), the callback of `$stateChangeError` is not run. If I do exactly the same, but outside of Ionic, [it works!](http://plnkr.co/edit/X3bfYZmimHqQ2qFLhI5m?p=preview)

Moreover, trying to delay the `resolve` rejection by doing `$timeout(defer.reject);` results in a different behaviour. Now it works in a browser as expected, but still doesn't work on a device. Trying to delay even more, results in success on device:

```
$timeout(function() {
  defer.reject();
}, 250); // Doesn't work for me with 200 or less
```

Can anyone shed light on this?

<kbd>[**SEE HERE HOW TO REPRODUCE THE ISSUE**](https://github.com/moroshko/ResolveIssue)</kbd>

Comment: Hi Misha. I just cloned your Github repo and ran the command: ionic run --device android The ionic loading modal comes up properly. Are you trying this on android or ios devices? Is there a specific device that you're using? Does this happen if you use the emulator?

Comment: Found a bug https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1751  updated my answer accordingly

Comment: @bhantol thank you, this helped me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience with Angular and the promise model. In order to resolve/reject a promise Angular must tick over one cycle of the JS event loop - nextTick - and this can be accomplished using $scope.apply() which is how we mock such things in unit tests.

This is an awesome [article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm) that talks about $timeout and $scope.$evalAsync - from what I can gather $timeout is evaluating the function in the next tick. Which is the reason that this code works the way you outlined.

```
resolve: {
  issue: function($q, $timeout) {
    var defer = $q.defer();
    //defer.reject();       // <---- no nextTick
    $timeout(defer.reject); // <---- $timeout evaluates on nextTick
    return defer.promise;
  }
}
```

This is another [article](http://olim7t.github.io/2013/08/19/angular-promise-implementation.html) that talks about the textTick implementation of $q.

I know that this doesnt solve your problem - but it should shed some light onto why this is happening! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

**1) $timeout needs to be more than 200**

First off - I have never seen constructs like $timeout(deferred.reject); I don't believe defered.reject returns any function that $timeout expects.

I tried 50 and it works.
Here is http://plnkr.co/edit/6NXZEXrfz3WHVqoaRYJB?p=preview
with timeout 50 or less but works i.e. All Good! is printed.

```
resolve: {
              test: function($q,  $timeout) {
                var defer = $q.defer(); 
                $timeout(function(){
                  defer.reject();
                },50);
                return defer.promise; 
              }
}
```

This is with stateChangeError outside the iconicPlatform.ready

**2) $stateChangeError not working**

I am thinking that this has to do with the timings. I don;t know the internals as to when the ionicPlatform.ready() gets executed but I am not sure if it is even necessary. Your `starter` module depends on it so it will be loaded. Sometimes seed projects have more than 'seed'.

UPDATED - Found a bug with respect to ready() on other devices. It seems that ready method is not getting executed.

https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1751