# How to change states when logging in or logging out with firebase without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I am trying to use resolve to check for the authentication state and direct the user to the appropriate view.

I am trying the following (see below), but it does not result in transferring to the appropriate states as it would have done when refreshing the page.

**app.js**

```
// Ionic Starter App

// angular.module is a global place for creating, registering and retrieving Angular modules
// 'starter' is the name of this angular module example (also set in a <body> attribute in index.html)
// the 2nd parameter is an array of 'requires'
// 'starter.controllers' is found in controllers.js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'firebase'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.run(["$rootScope", "$state", function($rootScope, $state) {
  $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeError", function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams, error) {
    // We can catch the error thrown when the $requireAuth promise is rejected
    // and redirect the user back to the home page
    if (error === "AUTH_REQUIRED") {
      console.log('stateChangeError')
      $state.go("app.login");
    }
  });
}])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

  var authResolve = {
    authReturn: function($state, $q, $timeout, Auth) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      var ref = Auth.refObj();


      ref.onAuth(authDataCallback)


      function authDataCallback(authData) {
        if (authData) {
          console.log("authDataCallback: User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
          defer.resolve(authData)
        }   else {
          console.log("authDataCallback: User is logged out");
          defer.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED')
        }
      }




      $timeout(function() { // See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/24945731/247243
          defer.reject('login');
      }, 250);

      return defer.promise;
    }
  };


  $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/menu.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })

  .state('app.login', {
    url: "/login",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
        controller: "LoginCtrl"
      }
    }
  })

  .state('app.profile', {
    url: "/profile",
    views: {
      'menuContent': {
        templateUrl: "templates/profile.html",
        resolve: authResolve
      }
    }
  })

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login'); //CHANGE TO HOME
});
```

**controller.js**

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {

})

.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $state, Auth) {

  var ref = Auth.refObj();
  var authData = ref.getAuth();

if (authData) {
  console.log("User " + authData.uid + " is logged in with " + authData.provider);
  $scope.authData = authData;
} else {
  console.log("User is logged out");
}

  $scope.signOut = function() {
    Auth.signOut();
  }

  $scope.signIn = function() {
    Auth.signIn();
  }

})


.factory('Auth', function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, $state) {

  // Register the callback to be fired every time auth state changes
  var ref = new Firebase("https://lovin.firebaseio.com");

  var signIn = function() {
    ref.authWithPassword({
        email    : 'sa.ibisevic@gmail.com',
        password : 'Maserati2014'
    }, authHandler);

    // logging users in
    function authHandler(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
        $state.go("app.login")
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        $state.go("app.profile")
      }
    }

  }

  var signOut = function() {
    ref.unauth();
    $state.go("app.login")
  }

  var authRef = function() {
    return $firebaseAuth(ref);
  }



  return {

    signIn: signIn,
    signOut: signOut,
    refObj: function() {
      return ref;
    },
    authRef: authRef

  }


})
```

**login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Login">


  <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>

  <ion-content>
    <h1>{{authData.uid}}</h1>

    <button class="button" ng-click="signIn()">Sign In</button>
    <button class="button" ng-click="signOut()">Sign Out</button>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: What is your objection to just looking it up from the database again?  If it's a performance issue, can you cache it?

Comment: No more to 1. Check whether user logged in, if a page requires login (resolve), then redirect to login state if the user logs out and 2. Update all views accordingly. Eg, authData.uid should become empty again in login.html when user logs out. The console does what is expected, but the pages are not "refreshed"

Comment: I think I neec to put $timeout somewherw but I dont really see where and how.

Comment: Also, the $stateChangeError never triggers, which is the function that I would have liked to work

Answer (score 0):

Beware that you can listen to the authentication state on the $firebaseSimpleLogin object. So you could do something like that:

```
 $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout', function(event) {

    $state.go('login');

  });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good example. Only I prefer using the new $firebaseAuth instead of the depreciated SimpleLogin. But thanks for the help.