# URL flickers between "localhost:8100" and "localhost:8100/some-route" with a white screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, localhost, promise

I was working on my ionic app and everything worked fine during a session, however, after restarting my computer and starting up the project again I cannot seem to get any display (besides a white one) in the browser or on the device. I have in addition hoped to an earlier branch and I still get the URL flickering between "`localhost:810`0" and "`localhost:8100/some-route`" with a white screen. Im assuming its my `app.js`'s structure that is causing this as my best guess would be that some route isn't being resolved correctly.

My app.js's structure looks like this. Im not sure if this is it but Im not sure what's best practice for the structure, assuming there is an issue with resolving one of the states in the problem. Thanks for the help

```
angular.module('underscore', [])
.factory('_', function() {
  return window._; 
});

angular.module('myapp', [...])
  .constant(...)
  .config(function(...) {
    var resolve = {
      <auth promise for route access>
      return defer.promise;
    }
    $http(<setup for http requests headers>);

    $stateProvider.state('app.some-route', {
      resolve: resolve,
      ... all my routes, some of which resolve ...      
    })
      .run(function(...);
```

Comment: You have two return's `return   return defer.promise;`... are you sure that's correct?

Comment: It was a typo setting up this question

Answer (score 0):

I guess I figured it out, I hope I don't get issue again if I start up this session another day, [ui-router resolve behaves strangely in Ionic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24945731/ui-router-resolve-behaves-strangely-in-ionic) was a commented out link in the project I adapted a few parts from and this got me pointed in the right direction as I found it was marked as an ionic 'bug' as this isnt an issue if ran just with angular my solution was found here https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1751. My issue was from the order of some of my scripts in my `index.html` I had

```
script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"
script src="other-dependencies.js"
script src="cordova.js"
script src="js/app.js"
script src="js/controllers.js"
script src="js/services.js"
```

and the order matters and my fix was by reordering like so

```
script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"
script src="cordova.js"
script src="js/app.js"
script src="js/controllers.js"
script src="js/services.js" 
script src="other-dependencies.js"
```

hope this helps someone